# Statistics with R Software - Data and intervals

Tags: r, statistics, intervals

I have the following data :

```
women_height <- c(105,110,112,112,118,119,120,120,125,126,
                  127,128,130,132,133,134,135,138,138,138,
                  138,142,145,148,148,150,151,154,154,158)
```

and the following intervals :

```
]104;114];]114;124];]124;134];]134;144];]144;154];]154;164];]164;174];]174;184]
```

How can I found how much women have an height between each interval ?
For exemple :

]104;114] --> 4 matches

]114;124] ---> 4 matches

...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a combination of `cut` (with use of `seq` for the breaks) and `table`:

```
table(cut(women_height, breaks=seq(104, 184, by=10)))

#(104,114] (114,124] (124,134] (134,144] (144,154] (154,164] (164,174] (174,184] 
#        4         4         8         6         7         1         0         0
```